# How to perform FIND, then perform AND, then perform OR with POPULATE in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a query that I wish to perform something similar as:

1. Archive does not exists AND
2. Owner Email in schema is in Query OR
3. Owner Email in Populated's schema is in Query

Below is what I have tried as of my understanding

```
    let docs = await Document.find({ archive: { $exists: false }})
      .and([{ owner_email: { $regex: localQuery } }])
      .or()
      .populate('owner_id', null, {
        email: { $regex: localQuery },
      });
```

So what I wish to do is, I have two schema, the user and the documents, User sometimes is shared along [as a librarian], then I wish to return, both, which matches the populated email or the actual owner's email.

Comment: I would try populating the collection first (don't forget .exectPopulate() after .populate()) and then, once all the fields that you intend to query are in place, do whatever you need to do.

Comment: Just to be clear - you want `owner_email`/`email` *not* to match `localQuery`, so it should actually be `{ owner_email: { $not: { $regex: localQuery } }}`, right? Or is `localQuery` itself negated?

Comment: @eol I am sorry, it should be, return if owner_email or email contains localQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mongoose's `populate()` method does not really "join" collections and rather makes another query to the database to populate after the `find()` operation, you can switch to an aggregation pipeline and use `$lookup` in order to match the email in the referenced field. So assuming your models look like:

```
const Document = mongoose.model('Document', {
    name: String,
    archive: String, 
    owner_email: String,
    owner: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person'}
});

const Person = mongoose.model('Person', {
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String
});
```

Then, you can do:

```
const result = await Document.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: Person.collection.name,
                localField: "owner",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "referencedOwner"
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                archive: {$exists: false},
                $or: [
                    {"referencedOwner.email": {$regex: localQuery}},
                    {"owner_email": {$regex: localQuery}}]
            }
        }
    ]);
```

Here's a working example on mongoplayground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/NqAvKIgujbm

Comment: Hi, your code does work! Thank you, 

I've also written a code that seems to working by:
1. find archive that is null, then perform Populate
2. Perform .filter on populated email and local schema's email [javascript]

Do you know if there is any bad in doing so as in indexing or stuff like that?

Comment: Oh sure, you can do the filtering/matching on the nodejs side as well, but if your dataset is huge you'll get better performance if you let mongo do it

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought so, will make a habit of using aggregate, find it somehow useful. Thank you